# Custom reason for word wrap in VS Code extension to enable working with multiline values in Json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I write Jsons for an API that often requires to have multiline values because scripts are in between the data in the attributes. I've written an extension for me that can escape and unescape multiline values, therefore I can cycle between those states:

```
{
  "value": "
    multiline
    value
  "
}
```

```
{
  "value": "multiline\n    value"
}
```

However, in the un-escaped, formatted, status, I have an invalid Json, which just causes trouble. I have to switch between escaped and unescaped states to do any Json operation (like format), which I work around by replacing `\n` with `\\n` and back.

I have even considered switching to another format, but neither of those I tried had a killer feature making me switch. Among those: Jsonc (no multiline value support), XML (hard to write and read, but supports multiline values and indentation), YAML (would be an option, but does not support indentation in multiline values).

Can I force VS Code to render a specific sequence of characters as line break (in this case, it would be `\\n`) without changing the document data? The intended functionality is like what the Alt+Z word wrap does, just in a different place.

Comment: you  can write a custom editor, or a webview that renders the JSON in multiline and allows the editing of the `textarea` and send the modifications back to the file

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I've found the following:

- it is not possible or hard to do to hijack the default editor and make it render lines in a way I want
- even if I managed to, it might have an underlying issue of not tokenizing long lines

I have decided to go in a way, where I define a custom language, because:
* the API has a constant Json structure
* I can define a new grammar for the API scripts and embed it to the Jsons
This approach seems to be a way to go for me, although it might be a temporary solution. I'm losing Json validations, therefore I do not get a Json new line in value error, but I'm also losing errors in missing commas. This is something I want to approach with the following precautions:

- if a JSON is valid and contains attributes of the API-defined classes, offer a button to switch to my defined language, which also un-escapes `\\\n` to `\n`
- if language is my language, escape the newlines and try to pass it to a JSON validation.